# context.getImageData() operation is insecure

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, filter

I want to realize a simple greyscale filter for HTML5 canvas, but I canot grab the Image data as pixels. I get security warnings from FF and Chrome. Finally the filter does not make the image grey.

[**JS FIDLE CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NEF8n/2/)

js:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');       
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
  if (image.width != canvas.width)
    canvas.width = image.width;
  if (image.height != canvas.height)
    canvas.height = image.height;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  filter(imageData);
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
image.src = "http://i0.gmx.net/images/302/17520302,pd=2,h=192,mxh=600,mxw=800,w=300.jpg";

function filter(imageData){
 var d = imageData.data;
   for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
     var r = d[i];
     var g = d[i + 1];
     var b = d[i + 2];
     d[i] = d[i + 1] = d[i + 2] = (r+g+b)/3;
   }
return imageData;
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to handle this error correctly you should use `try catch`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a security feature.  From [W3](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/Overview.html#dom-context-2d-getimagedata):

> The `getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh)` method must, if the canvas element's origin-clean flag is set to false, throw a `SecurityError` exception

This is to prevent malicious site owners from loading potentially private images that the user's browser has access to onto the canvas, then sending the data to their own servers. The origin-clean can be turned off if:

> - The element's 2D context's drawImage() method is called with an HTMLImageElement or an HTMLVideoElement whose origin is not the same
>     as that of the Document object that owns the canvas element.
> - The element's 2D context's drawImage() method is called with an HTMLCanvasElement whose origin-clean flag is false.
> - The element's 2D context's fillStyle attribute is set to a CanvasPattern object that was created from an HTMLImageElement or an
>     HTMLVideoElement whose origin was not the same as that of the Document
>     object that owns the canvas element when the pattern was created.
> - The element's 2D context's fillStyle attribute is set to a CanvasPattern object that was created from an HTMLCanvasElement whose
>     origin-clean flag was false when the pattern was created.
> - The element's 2D context's strokeStyle attribute is set to a CanvasPattern object that was created from an HTMLImageElement or an
>     HTMLVideoElement whose origin was not the same as that of the Document
>     object that owns the canvas element when the pattern was created.
> - The element's 2D context's strokeStyle attribute is set to a CanvasPattern object that was created from an HTMLCanvasElement whose
>     origin-clean flag was false when the pattern was created.
> - The element's 2D context's fillText() or strokeText() methods are invoked and end up using a font that has an origin that is not the
>     same as that of the Document object that owns the canvas element.
>
> [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements)

Comment: so how can I get the data now?

Comment: @daisy:  By fetching the remote image from the server the page is being loaded from, and having the JavaScript load the image from that server.  This ensures that you're accessing a non-private image.

Comment: adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` solved the issue for me

Comment: That should be `image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"` (capital `O`).

Comment: It works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: Actually, it works, but you **must** set ``crossOrigin`` before setting ``src``.

Answer (score 15):

Here's an answer that actually solves the problem:

After creating the new Image, use

```
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

Comment: For me it works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Comment: Same here, Firefox doesn't seem to respect this.

Comment: Actually, it works, but you **must** set ``crossOrigin`` before setting ``src``.

Comment: Does not work in Firefox in 2023

Comment: FWIW, it works for me in Ubuntu Firefox 121.0.1, e.g. here's a JS Fiddle with an updated image link and [@stackers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929321/stackers) code fix applied: https://jsfiddle.net/5hLxjzu9/11/