# Loading/security issue when drawing images on a canvas

Tags: javascript, cors, html5-canvas

My question might be stupid, but I'm stuck with a simple task.

I'm writing a web browser game where I load images from a local folder to a 2d canvas, then, at some time, redraw it with `getImageData()`.
The code sample is the following

```
let img = new Image()
// img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
img.src = "assets/hidden.png"

let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")

img.onload = () => {
    console.log("loaded img", img.src)
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)

    let c = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 10, 10)
}
```

The original problem was that calling `getImageData()` causes `Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.`
So I added `img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"` ([context.getImageData() operation is insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035106/context-getimagedata-operation-is-insecure)) to overcome this, but now the image is not loaded at all. How do I normally use images in canvas?

Comment: Are you running a server or just opening the HTML file? When the image is not loaded at all, is there anything in the console? Does `onload` run? I don't know if it matters, but I usually set the `.src` property last, after `onload` and other properties have been set.

Comment: @ggorlen it is a static html page with this script and the assets folder located at the same place. Image is just not loading, nothing in the console. If I set `crossOrigin = "anonymous"` after loading, I get the previous security error

Comment: OK, I'd try running a server: `python -m http.server` and navigate to `localhost:8000` in your browser.

Comment: well, when a server is run, it works.. thanks for help! But would it work if I publish my game at a web-page?

Comment: It should, assuming the images are on the same domain. It was probably a CORS issue.

Comment: Canonical for running a local server [How to run html file on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497334/how-to-run-html-file-on-localhost)